# What is the Big-O of Sudoku using brute force backtracking?

Tags: big-o, factorial, sudoku, exponential, constraint-satisfaction

I was wondering what the Big-O of a simple brute force backtracking Sudoku solving algorithm was.

Sudoku has 4 constraints:

1. cell - one cell can contain one number max
2. region - numbers in the region must be all different
3. row - numbers on the same row must be all different
4. column - numbers on the same column must be all different

Given the 9x9 grid:

```
3|___|___________
_|_ _|_ _ _ _ _ _
_|___|_ _ _ _ _ _
_|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

I think the row, column and region constraints are all O(n!) since (n)(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)(n-6)(n-7)(n-8) for each row, column and region as they get filled up.

But given that there must be a minimum of 17 given solutions for a unique 9x9 Sudoku solution to exist, I'm not sure now. The number of permutations are O(n^(n^2 - k)) where k = 17 for pure brute force but this does not include constraint satisfaction, which I'm sure is either exponential O(c^n) or factorial O(n!) at least.

So the question again is what is the Big-O of sudoku using brute force backtracking with constraint satisfaction and why? O(log n!)?

Comment: Depends on how clever your algorithm is.

Comment: the algorithm is a really naive brute force backtracking one - how can I find the Big-O?

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer might considered a bit picky, the complexity is `O(1)`; as Sudoku is played on a grid of fixed size of `9*9` cells and each cell admits exactly one of `9` different states, namely an assignment of one of the values in `{1,...,9}`, using a brute force approach to extend a given partial assignment takes constant time. Otherwise, it would have to be clarified what exactly the `n` mentioned in the question would be.

That being said, if `n` is supposed to be the board size, i.e. there are `n*n`,`m` is the number of possible states per cell, `b1` is the number of regions and `b2` is the region size (i.e. each of the `b1` regions has `b2*b2` cells) the runtime complexity can be roughly estimated by the following reasoning. There are `m^(n*n)` states of the board; checking if a state of the board is legal with respect to the sudou rules takes `(n^2)*b1*(b2^2)` operations, namely checking uniqueness of each cell state in each row, column and block. In total, a feasible assignment can be determied

```
O(m^{n*n}*(n^2)*b1*(b2^2))
```

steps.

Comment: Note: there are 4*4 and 16*16 sudokus.

Comment: n is the dimensions of the Sudoku board e.g. 4x4, 9x9, 16x16, etc.

Comment: @Codor that's not right because O(m^(n*n)) would be the total number of permutations the board can have so anything over that would be wrong.

Comment: @Codor perhaps it's O(m^(n/c)) where c is the row, column and regional constraints